# What is the equivalent of GCC's fno-strict-aliasing flag for ICC, the Intel Compiler?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, intel, icc, compiler-flags

The Intel compiler appears to accept the -fno-strict-aliasing flag verbatim, but I have not seen that behavior documented anywhere, and the flag may be ignored. Flags such as -no-ansi-alias look related, but I want to be sure I specify exactly the right behavior.

Answer (score 1):

ICC accepts most gcc switches and does the right thing with them. If you want to use the ICC-specific switch though then I think this is probably the one:

```
-[no-]ansi-alias
          enable/disable(DEFAULT) use of ANSI aliasing rules optimizations;
          user asserts that the program adheres to these rules
```

Answer (score 1):

When these replies were posted, Intel compilers did in fact default to -fno-ansi-alias, but it has since changed (at least for linux).